# How do you access the user's phone background?

Tags: ios, swift, background, widget, lockscreen

There isn’t really much to this question, but is it somehow possible to programmatically set the user's lock screen background?

Or maybe add a photo to the image folder a user has chosen, for their "Photo shuffle lock screen widget"?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Forums:

> There isn't a way for an app to change the wallpaper settings. Apple doesn't make those settings available, so the only option on an official version of iOS is to save the images so that the user can manually change them in Settings.

Link [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/9584). This would be a privacy risk if you could change the wallpaper without the user setting something in `Settings` - apps could change wallpaper without confirmation. My suggestion would be to provide a way to save images to the user's photo library (see [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-save-images-to-the-users-photo-library)), and then giving them a link to `Settings` to change the wallpaper to that. Once again, there is **NO PUBLIC API** to change wallpaper programatically.